# After an ajax update to page, clicking a new link then back button shows outdated content in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, browser-cache, back-button

I've seen a bunch of questions about this on SO but none solved my problem (not sure if slightly different issue or same issue but those fixes did not work for some reason).

Here is the scenario:

- user enters something in a form (say the number 1) and a div on the page updates with some content next to it (this is done via jquery ajax)
- the user clicks to a link to a new page, and then the back button
- now the page shows correctly in Firefox, but not in Chrome (have not tested others)

In Chrome, the 1 still appears in the form but the div on the page is no longer there (as if the page had just loaded).

In Firefox, it shows div and the 1 correctly.

I've tried changing the url hash when the ajax request completes and a few other things to invalidate the cache.  But Chrome still doesn't show the correct version of the page.

I would also be ok if it made a request to the server to completely reload the page, but I haven't gotten it to do this either.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: could you please give the code for the ajax call `$.ajax( ... )` and maybe link to the other questions you've seen on SO?

Comment: Sure, the ajax call just looks like this https://gist.github.com/8e8b27a86105380901aa  Here are some of the SO questions I checked: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=ajax%20update%20page%20back%20button%20cache%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=dc3ab67f8cfe3a0a&bpcl=35277026&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1206&bih=1032  Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Possible reading: http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/14-01-07/please-respect-the-back-button.aspx